# Database not configuring for Stretch when attempting to enable Stretch feature in SQL 2016 RC0

Tags: sql-server-2016

I'm getting an error on the final hurdle when enabling my database to become a stretch database onto azure via the stretch DB wizard. The key part of the error log appears to be the following:

--

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)".
The server '' is not accessible. Ensure that the remote server exists and the Azure SQL DB Firewall Rules permit access to the server.

--

I've followed the instructions as close to [THIS](http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2015/09/15/stretch-you-on-premise-databasetable-to-azure-sql-database-with-stretchdb-sql-server-2016/) as I can, however although it seems it should be straightforward, something is going wrong. Please can anyone suggest what might be the issue, and how I can fix it?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That blog is really old given the product is still in pre-release state with new releases each month. Suggest you look at the official documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935011.aspx).

That aside, looks like SQL Server is not able to reach the server in Azure. How are you getting this error? From the wizard or via TSQL scripts? The wizard allows you to create a new server as part of the stretch process and attempts to set the right Azure firewall rule for the public IP address of your SQL Server. To eliminate Azure firewall rule as a potential blocker, you can try setting it to listen on 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 but once you verify it's working, remember to change it back to whatever range your public IP address really is.

If you stretch via TSQL, you'll need to create an Azure SQL server and set the firewall rules first (via portal). Once the server is created, you then use the server name (something.database.windows.net) in your TSQL script to enable the database for Stretch.

Of course, this is all assuming your credential has permissions to create servers and databases in Azure.